# Using ngContainer or ngTemplate?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a grid, the header title is very long. The haeder title contains two words. If I don't use resizeable column, it is hard to see the header title. So I want to split the title into two lines; each line displays one word. For example, the header title is `Company VeryVerylongName`. I want to split into `Company` and `VerrVerylongName`.

I guess that I can use `ngContainer` or `ngTemplate` in the `kendo-ui-column`

```
<kendo-grid-column width="40">
  // here I need something...
        </kendo-grid-column>
```

So what is the option?

[Stackblize Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfymsd) or [telerik grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/get-started/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set desired `width` for the column and use style property `white-space: normal` for `<ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate>`.

`<ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate>` is used for setting custom kendo Grid Header Template.

[As mdn says about white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

> Sequences of white space are collapsed. Newline characters in the
>   source are handled the same as other white space. Lines are broken as
>   necessary to fill line boxes.

So the whole code should look like this:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
      <kendo-grid-column field="Id" >
            <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
              {{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Company VeryVerylongName" [width]="180">
            <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
              <span style="white-space: normal">{{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})</span>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Contact VeryVerylongName">
            <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
              {{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ContactTitle">
            <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
              {{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column> 
        <kendo-grid-column field="City">
            <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
              {{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>
```

It can be seen at [work stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfymsd-u5umkv?file=app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 2):

`<ng-container>`:
 if you are used nested structural directives like *ngIf or *ngFor

`<ng-template>` can have a nasty syntax and it is used if you need a view "snippet" that you want to stamp.

Answer (score 1):

I believe **neither** of those options are not suitable for your case.

`<ng-container>` is Angular element for cases when you need more than one structural directive on host element (for instance you want *ngFor and *ngIf both on same element). In this case you could put  . Once Angular evaluates template only content of  element will be included in DOM but will exclude  itself so you don't introduce another level of HTML and this is the reason why you can't bind any styling to it.

`<ng-template>` and its content on the other hand is **never** displayed by default! It is very useful for defining template of repeatable blocks or some fallbacks, but you have to explicitly 'call' it to make it appear on the screen.

One very popular use case is ngIfElse case:

```html
  <ng-container *ngIf="name; else anonymous">Hello {{name}}</ng-container>
  <!-- ... -->
  <ng-template #anonymous>
    Hello stranger!
  </ng-template>
```

If name is defined, you will see Hello with name on the screen otherwise you will see Hello anonymous. Similarly as ng-container, only content of ng-template will be included in DOM this element itself can't be styled.

In your case try to use simple  block and put some styling on it and you should be able to achieve what you want.

For better understanding of `<ng-container>` and `<ng-template>` I would suggest you [this blog post](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/) and [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)

Comment: I thought about simple blocks. For example, use two `div`. However the blocks are still needed to place a container. It can't be directly put in `kendo-grid-column`. So this is my question...Maybe we consider `ng-template`?